# Flash player debugger plugin crashes on Mac OS [tried many version of the plugin and browsers, all of them crash]

Tags: firefox, macos, safari, flash

I recently started using Mac OS X for a flex/actionscript project and having a problem with flash player debugger plugin for the browsers:

- OSX: 10.6.3
- Browsers I tried: firefox, safari and chrome
- Flashplayer debug "Flash Player 10 Plugin content debugger (Intel-based Macs)

  Whenever I open a page containing a flash content, my browser crashes due to flash player plugin's crash.

I checked the version of my flash player debug plugin with http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html

and as the version checker is written in flash, my browser crashes a few seconds later.

I am using version 10,0,42,2 (debug edition: yes)

This is what I see in the crash log:

```
Process:         WebKitPluginHost [338]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKitPluginHost.app/Contents/MacOS/WebKitPluginHost
Identifier:      com.apple.WebKit.PluginHost
Version:         6533 (6533.13)
Build Info:      WebKitPluginHost-75331300~1
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  WebKitPluginAgent [337]

PlugIn Path:       /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Flash Player
PlugIn Identifier: com.macromedia.Flash Player.plugin
PlugIn Version:    10.0.45.2 (1.0.4f458472)

Date/Time:       2010-06-09 21:18:23.408 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.3 (10D2094)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          1232 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           2
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  61 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2
Anonymous UUID:                      6765603E-22AC-4AA6-8EFF-215234877FF4

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000197003e4
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

Any ideas how can I track this issue ?

Cheers,
 -A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to version 10.1 resolved the issue.